# What happens to activity when the navigation pane is drawn?

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an activity my app to determine if Gps status is on or off. Works fine if i redirect to the settings activity and resumes but the onResume override method doesn't work when the navigation pane is closed. Any solutions ?

Comment: Kindly make your question clear. Need better explanation please.

Comment: I am trying to show gps status on a textview. this works perfectly when user leaves the application to turn on or off gps in phone settings in the onResume() override method. but while the application is open, when I draw the navigation pane, and turn on or off the gps, the status in my application doesn't change.

Comment: @Ragu I would like a toggle in my activity be updated when the gps is turn on/off from the android notification pane will my app is open.